# Postgres regex: Behavior of \s and \S and character class seems wrong

Tags: regex, postgresql

The documentation says that \s is whitespace and \S is not whitespace. So far, nothing new to regex users.

But let's check some return values:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abc a c' FROM 'a\\sc');
'a c'

SELECT SUBSTRING('abc a c' FROM 'a[\\s]c'); -- Note the character class
'a c'

SELECT SUBSTRING('abc a c' FROM 'a\\Sc');
'abc'

SELECT SUBSTRING('abc a c' FROM 'a[\\S]c'); -- Note the character class
ERROR:  invalid regular expression: invalid escape \ sequence
```

So it seems, \s can be used in a character class and \S cannot. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html):

> Within bracket expressions, \d, \s, and \w lose their outer brackets,
>   and \D, \S, and \W are illegal.

In any case, the brackets seem redundant since `\s` and `\S` themselves are character classes.

The following syntax works for me as an alternative to `a[\\S]c`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abc a c' FROM 'a[^[:space:]]c');
```

Comment: Thx, I overlooked this. BTW, of course the brackets are redundant in my simplified example code.

Comment: The reason they are illegal is because `a[^\s]c` works just fine for negation.